# How to submit binaries to the armel repository?

Tags: repository, arm

I often find myself compiling binaries for my tablet, since it's running the arm version of Ubuntu Precise and there is not a lot of newer software available for it.

As an example, Gimp 2.8 took like half a day to compile but now that I've got it, I'd like to make it available for everyone else.

Comment: So most software isn't available through `apt-get` if you have an ARM device? You have to compile everything? What if there's lots of dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

New versions can be backported by following the [Ubuntu Backport process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports).   Ubuntu doesn't accept binary uploads.  Also, PPAs do not provide binaries for arm, only amd64 and i386.

The simplest way to proceed is to use the *requestbackport* tool from ubuntu-dev-tools.

An example in this case would be:

```
$ requestbackport -d precise -s quantal gimp
```

Which provides the output:

```
requestbackport:  * LP: #1006424: Please backport babl 0.1.10-1 (main) from quantal  https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1006424
requestbackport:  * LP: #1040756: Please backport fftw3 3.3.2-3.1ubuntu1 (main) and fftw3-mpi from quantal  https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1040756
requestbackport:  * LP: #1006426: Please backport gegl 0.2.0-1ubuntu1 (main) from quantal  https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1006426
requestbackport:  * LP: #1002780: Please backport gimp 2.8.0-2ubuntu1 (main) from quantal  https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1002780
```

So, you can see that the request has already been started in LP: #1002780.

Comment: That page is super confusing. Say I want to contribute/get gimp 2.8 backport/ available to the public.  What is my first step?